# Modem/Router combo keeps switching to Bridged mode

Tags: wireless-router, wifi-configuration, gateway, cable-modem

I have a SBG6700-AC modem/router combo that was purchased at Best Buy a couple of years ago. WiFi routing was enabled out of the box and worked fine until I hooked up the modem yesterday at a new location with a new account from Spectrum. For some reason, the Gateway Mode keeps setting itself to Bridged. Changing it back to Routed reboots the machine and it is in Bridged mode when it comes back up. The technician at Spectrum assured me that it has nothing to do with them (in spite of [this post](https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r30635517-Internet-DG1670A-keeps-switching-to-Bridged-mode) which seems to suggest Spectrum's forerunner TWC did exactly that) and suggested I try a factory reset. It was a pain, but I agreed to try it. Same thing. If I disconnect the cable and then change it back to Routed mode, it stays in Routed mode until the cable is connected. Connecting the cable cycles the modem again and it immediately comes up in Bridged mode.

What is going on and how can I fix it? If it is something that Spectrum is doing, how can I prove it?

Comment: are you attaching this device inside the LAN of the Spectrum provided modem/router, or instead of the Spectrum provided modem/router?

Comment: I am using this device instead of a Spectrum provided modem/router.

Comment: so you are plugging in the Coaxial cable, and that's when it reboots?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Without the coaxial cable, I can reboot the modem as many times as I want and it stays in Routed mode (not that it is actually usable without the coax).  As soon as the coaxial cable is introduced, the modem reboots and comes up in Bridged mode.

Comment: I'd probably start by calling the company again, and ask that they review your service codes since you are bringing your own device. Service codes have a lot of impact on the gateway device. when it reboots, is that immediately, or after a minute or so? That behavior in itself is suspect, so I do wonder if the device is fully functional. They could be pushing config to you, and then triggering a reboot, but that should only happen once. They do use SurfBoard modems, so I wonder if you are getting config meant for one of their models.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **@Frank Thomas** for giving me the breadcrumbs I needed to get the multiple technicians at Spectrum to consider that the problem might just be on their end.  I did have to break down and call Arris (who confirmed that they hear this all the time) before they (Spectrum) would help.  In the end, it turns out that Spectrum had, in fact, used the wrong service codes and my modem/router combo was set up as a 'modem' in their system and not a 'gateway'.

Comment: glad you got it working. Generally you need multiple techs to diagnose a service code issue (one to bork it with an old code, and another 3 to notice) so that's not surprising.  I wouldn't be at all surprised if the problem was your account hadn't subscribed for an up-charge for WiFi service, so when it was detected, the device was reconfigured.